# groupBy on dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to do groupBy on dataframe with  two columns whereas second column has a category value. Plz help me for the correct syntax in scala .
I tried this way but its wrong.

```
df.groupBy("col1", "col2" == "Buy").count
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df.where($"col2" === "Buy").groupBy("col1").count`

Comment: Thank you. But it gives the below compilation error [error]   (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.s
ql.Row] <and>
[error]   (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[o
rg.apache.spark.sql.Row]
[error]  cannot be applied to (Boolean)
[error]                 val df1 = dfInvent.where($"TRANSACTION_TYPE" == "Buy").g
roupBy("PRODUCT_ID").count.show

Comment: `===` instead of  `==`

Comment: working. Thank you!!